# Using WordPress primarily as a front-end, while using an express server in the back-end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, express, backend

Is it possible to use WordPress as a front-end, allowing me to quickly put up a design for the website, and use a node js server hosted elsewhere as a back-end in which i’ll load important data from

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do whatever you want.
The question you're asking is if you can use WordPress, which is hardcoded in PHP, a server-side language, with Node.js.

Yes, you can do that, if you complete remake WordPress to be based on Node.js instead of PHP.